# how I fix this error code: Please update the following components: Animated?

Tags: reactjs, jquery-animate

I use animation with React and I get this warning on the console:

Please update the following components: Animated

I use this libary:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-css

I want to ask you how I can fix it

Code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";
import { Form } from './components/Form.jsx';

const App = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    wohnort: ''
  });

  const [finish, setFinish] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const nameInput = name;

    setForm({
      ...form,
      [nameInput]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    if(form.name != '' && form.age != '' && form.wohnort != '') {
      setFinish(1);
    }
  };

  if(finish) {
    return (<Animated animationIn="bounceInLeft" animationOut="fadeOut" isVisible={true}>
    <div className='bg-white p-20'>
        hello world ;)
    </div>
</Animated>)
  } else {
    return (
      <>
      <Form 
        onChange={handleChange}
        onSave={handleSave}
      />
      </>
    )
  }
};


export default App;
```